# Environment variables not working in development branch - Next.js Vercel

Tags: next.js, vercel

I have two branches - `main` and `development` - and the following environment variables:

```
api_username=*****
api_secret=***************
```

It is deployed on vercel, now the thing is it is working properly on the main deployed branch but not on the development branch.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Can you make sure if you are using the same project for both environments, Since environment variables are per project in Vercel.

Also, can you check if there is a mismatch between the branch for the development environments and the domain assigned to that branch?

Since you can use environments variables per environment and per branch at the same time.

[image]

This is also mentioned in their [docs](https://vercel.com/docs/concepts/projects/environment-variables#preview-environment-variables):

> When you add a Preview Environment Variable, you can choose to apply to all Preview branches or you can select a specific branch